# Opinion modifier of reappearing countries

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Countries can disappear when they lose all of their lands.

However, they can be again by releasing them (as vassals or through a peace deal, big enough revolts).

How is the opinion modifier of a country which existed, disappeared and reappeared? Is the opinion recalculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tag (country), if removed from the game keeps their opinion modifiers till end of month.

If country ceases to exist on, say, April 10th in a peace deal when you full annex them and later you release them on the May 1st - they will lose all opinion modifiers they had before the full annexation.